# What are the differences between "clean in between the fingers" and "clean between the fingers"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, expressions, prepositional-phrases

I'm teaching my little children to wash their hands.

Why do people say "**clean in between your fingers**"?

Why not "**clean between your fingers**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. *In* is sometimes added just for emphasis, just as we might say "The ornament is *up* on top of the bookshelf", where the only function of *up* is to draw attention to the high position of the ornament.

Answer (score 1):

Careful English avoids this.  For example:

> Where are you at?

To answer your question, the correct thing to say is "clean between your fingers."